# What to do if i have 806 CC using DSNMTV01

Tags: db2, jcl, ims-db

I try to read some data from IMS DB and write it into db2 table using DSNMTV01.
But I have 806 CC ( REQUESTED MODULE DSNMTV01 NOT FOUND ).

```
//USER19    JOB NOTIFY=&SYSUID,MSGCLASS=A,MSGLEVEL=(1,1),REGION=360M
//DLIBATCH PROC MBR=TEMPNAME,PSB=,BUF=7,                            
//            SPIE=0,TEST=0,EXCPVR=0,RST=0,PRLD=,                   
//            SRCH=0,CKPTID=,MON=N,LOGA=0,FMTO=T,                   
//            IMSID=,SWAP=,DBRC=,IRLM=,IRLMNM=,                     
//             BKO=N,IOB=,SSM=,APARM=,                              
//            RGN=1024K,                                            
//*           SOUT=A,LOGT=2400,SYS2=,                               
//            SOUT=A,SYS2=,                                         
//            LOCKMAX=,GSGNAME=,TMINAME=                            
//S0 EXEC PGM=IEFBR14                                               
//IEFRDER  DD DSN=DFSD10.IMSLOG,DISP=(OLD,DELETE),VOL=SER=H1SYS1,   
//         UNIT=SYSDA                                               
//*----------------------------------------------------------       
//G      EXEC PGM=DFSRRC00,REGION=&RGN,                             
//            PARM=(DLI,&MBR,&PSB,&BUF,                             
//            &SPIE&TEST&EXCPVR&RST,&PRLD,                          
//            &SRCH,&CKPTID,&MON,&LOGA,&FMTO,                       
//            &IMSID,&SWAP,&DBRC,&IRLM,&IRLMNM,                     
//            &BKO,&IOB,&SSM,'&APARM',                              
//            &LOCKMAX,&GSGNAME,&TMINAME)                           
//STEPLIB  DD DSN=DFSD10.&SYS2.SDFSRESL,DISP=SHR                    
//         DD DSN=DFSD10.&SYS2.PGMLIB,DISP=SHR                      
//         DD DSN=USER19.LOAD,DISP=SHR                              
//DFSRESLB DD DSN=DFSD10.&SYS2.SDFSRESL,DISP=SHR                    
//IMS      DD DSN=DFSD10.PSBLIB,DISP=SHR                            
//         DD DSN=DFSD10.DBDLIB,DISP=SHR                            
//PROCLIB  DD DSN=DFSD10.&SYS2.PROCLIB,DISP=SHR                     
//IEFRDER  DD DSN=DFSD10.IMSLOG,DISP=(NEW,KEEP),VOL=SER=H1SYS1,     
//         DCB=(RECFM=VB,BLKSIZE=1920,                              
//         LRECL=1916,BUFNO=2),SPACE=(TRK,(1,1)),UNIT=SYSDA         
//SYSUDUMP DD SYSOUT=&SOUT,                                         
//         DCB=(RECFM=FBA,LRECL=121,BLKSIZE=1024),                  
//         SPACE=(605,(500,500),RLSE,,ROUND)                        
//IMSMON   DD DUMMY                              
// PEND                                          
//STEP1 EXEC DLIBATCH,MBR=DSNMTV01,PSB=DFSIVP11, 
//          DBRC=N,BKO=Y                         
//G.SYSPRINT DD SYSOUT=*                         
//G.DFSVSAMP DD *                                
VSRBF=16384,80                                   
/*                                                
//*                                              
//G.DFSIVD1 DD DSN=DFSD10.DFSIVD1,DISP=SHR       
//G.DFSIVD1I DD DSN=DFSD10.DFSIVD1I,DISP=SHR     
//*                                              
//G.DDOTV02 DD SYSOUT=*,RECFM=V,LRECL=4092       
//G.DDITV02 DD *                                 
DBBG,SYS1,DSNMIN10,,A,-,,USR19PL,READIMS         
/*                                               
//* THIS IS THE FOR LOAD OR UPDAT DATA           
//                                               
**************************** Bottom of Data *****
```

Have anybody some ideas whats wrong?
I try to srchfor DSNMTV in dfsd10,and I can find it in dfsd10.sdsfresl.. So, why i have 806 CC

Comment: UPD: I add more 1 lib into steplib and now rc=0. But unfortunately data not put into db2 table ( I use pl/1 pgm).

Comment: It's probably a an error in your program that your DB2 is not updated.

Comment: Thank U, Bill for your help. I resolve my problem. I have no grants